# Adding year switcher to jQuery's datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

In jQuery's datepicker you have on top the `<` `>`  icons to switch months. 
I'd like to add `<<` and `>>` to switch years, how can I get it like that?

I do not mean the dropdown for years and months, as I'm already using them, just figured it'd be easier to use.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two options [`prevText`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-prevText) and [`nextText`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-nextText) done specifically for that:

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
    prevText: '<<',
    nextText: '>>'
});
```